# Cambiar a Español Virtual Keyborad jquery

Tags: jquery, teclado

tengo este teclado virtual que he cogido de `https://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/docs/layouts.html` En esta web hay un apartado "Layouts" que se supone que te permite cambiar el idioma de este pero no se como hacerlo.

```js
$('#idUsuario').keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty' })
```

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%; left: 40%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }

#contenedor{
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/css/keyboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive  ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <div id="contenedor"> 
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUsuario"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="N&uacute;meros y letra may&uacute;scula y sin espacios"  name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca DNI o CIF" required />          
     </div>
     <div id="idTextoError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
     
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por un lado tienes que importar el javascript `spanish.min.js` para el `layout` (los botones) y por otro `es.min.js` para el lenguaje (los textos).

Estas son los CDN:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/layouts/spanish.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/languages/es.min.js
```

Luego, pásale al método `keyboard` las opciones `layout` y `language` con el idioma.

```
$('#idUsuario').keyboard({ 
    layout: 'spanish-qwerty',
    language: ['es']
});
```

Observarás que hay una pequeña errata en el botón Aceptar (pone Acceptar). Bájate el javascript `es.min.js` y cambia los textos a tu gusto:

```js
$('#idUsuario').keyboard({ 
layout: 'spanish-qwerty',
language: ['es']
});
```

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%; left: 40%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }

#contenedor{
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/css/keyboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/layouts/spanish.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/languages/es.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive  ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <div id="contenedor"> 
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUsuario"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="N&uacute;meros y letra may&uacute;scula y sin espacios"  name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca DNI o CIF" required />          
     </div>
     <div id="idTextoError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
     
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para hacerlo debes agregar un layout.js en donde tengas las teclas correspondiente al idioma y un language/es.js para realizar la traducción de los botones "accept, cancel, etc..". Esto lo puedes sacar del repositorio [Mottie/Keyboard](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard). Layout funciona bien, pero como dice en la documentación es.js está incompleto y con algunos errores de traducción. El segundo no lo veo extremadamente necesario, pero si lo deseas puedes corregir los errores de traducción que tenga y usarlo. En este caso yo apliqué algunas correcciones. Saludos!

**Archivos necesarios:**

- [layout.js](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/blob/master/layouts/spanish.js)
- [es.js](https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard/blob/master/languages/es.js)

**Ejemplo:**

```js
jQuery.keyboard.layouts['spanish-qwerty'] = {
 'name' : 'spanish-qwerty',
 'lang' : ['es'],
 'normal' : [
  "\u007c 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 \' \u00bf {bksp}",
  "{tab} q w e r t y u i o p \u0301 +",
  "a s d f g h j k l \u00f1 \u007b \u007d {enter}",
  "{shift} < z x c v b n m , . - {shift}",
  "{accept} {alt} {space} {alt} {cancel}"
 ],
 'shift' : [
  "\u00b0 ! \" # $ % & / ( ) = ? \u00a1 {bksp}",
  "{tab} Q W E R T Y U I O P \u0308 *",
  "A S D F G H J K L \u00d1 \u005b \u005d {enter}",
  "{shift} > Z X C V B N M ; : _ {shift}",
  "{accept} {alt} {space} {alt} {cancel}"
 ],
 'alt' : [
  "\u00ac 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 \\ \u00bf {bksp}",
  "{tab} @ w e r t y u i o p \u0301 \u0303",
  "a s d f g h j k l \u00f1 \u0302 \u0300 {enter}",
  "{shift} < z x c v b n m , . - {shift}",
  "{accept} {alt} {space} {alt} {cancel}"
 ],
 'alt-shift' : [
  "\u00b0 ! \" # $ % & / ( ) = ? \u00a1 {bksp}",
  "{tab} Q W E R T Y U I O P \u0308 *",
  "A S D F G H J K L \u00d1 \u005b \u005d {enter}",
  "{shift} > Z X C V B N M ; : _ {shift}",
  "{accept} {alt} {space} {alt} {cancel}"
 ]
};


jQuery.keyboard.language.es = {
 language: 'Espa\u00f1ol (Spanish)',
 display : {
  'a'      : '\u2714:Aceptar (Cambio+Inscribir)', // check mark - same action as accept
  'accept' : 'Aceptar:Acceptar (Cambio+Inscribir)',
  //'alt'    : 'AltGr:Grafemas Alternativos',
  'b'      : '\u2190:Retroceso',    // Left arrow (same as &larr;)
  'bksp'   : 'Retroceder:Retroceso',
  'c'      : '\u2716:Cancelar (Esc)', // big X, close - same action as cancel
  'cancel' : 'Cancelar:Cancelar (Esc)',
  'clear'  : 'C:Vaciar',             // clear num pad
  'combo'  : '\u00f6:Alternar las Teclas Combinados',
  'dec'    : ',:Decimal',           // decimal point for num pad (optional), change '.' to ',' for European format
  'e'      : '\u21b5:Inscribir',        // down, then left arrow - enter symbol
  'enter'  : 'Enter:Inscribir',
  'lock'   : '\u21ea Bloq:Mayús', // caps lock
  's'      : '\u21e7:Cambio',        // thick hollow up arrow
  //'shift'  : 'Cambio:Cambio',
  'sign'   : '\u00b1:Cambiar Signo',  // +/- sign for num pad
  'space'  : '&nbsp;:Espacio',
  't'      : '\u21e5:Tab',          // right arrow to bar (used since this virtual keyboard works with one directional tabs)
  'tab'    : '\u21e5 Tab:Tab'       // \u21b9 is the true tab symbol (left & right arrows)
 },
 wheelMessage : 'Utilice la rueda del mouse para ver otras teclas'
};

$('#idUsuario').keyboard({
 
  language:'es',
  layout:'spanish-qwerty',
});

//Esta linea solo la agregué para abrir automaticamente el teclado y facilitar las pruebas.
$('#idUsuario').focus();
```

```css
.Absolute-Center {
  
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%; left: 40%; bottom: 0; right: 0;
 }

#contenedor{
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/css/keyboard.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/virtual-keyboard/1.28.7/js/jquery.keyboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="Absolute-Center is-Responsive  ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <div id="contenedor"> 
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUsuario"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"  title="N&uacute;meros y letra may&uacute;scula y sin espacios"  name="txtUsuario" placeholder="Introduzca DNI o CIF" required />          
     </div>
     <div id="idTextoError" class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none"></div>
     
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div>
```